# Data not being passed through Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have a slightly confusing issue,  I am trying to send location data from a tableview through to a mapkit.  My tableview loads the various bits of info to list the names of the location, when I click a cell it segues into a navigation view with the data, however it doesnt seem to be sending the data and errors with found nil issue.  I did have this same tableview segueing to a different controller and it worked without issue.

This is my prepareForSegue on my main Viewcontroller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mapLocation" {
        if let detailsVC = segue.destination as? mapLocation {
            if let tr = sender as? newTracks {
                detailsVC.track = tr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mapkit view to segue to

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class mapLocation: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var track: newTracks!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sourceloaction = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: track.lat, longitude: track.lon)
    let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: track.lat, longitude: track.lon)

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceloaction, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)

    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

    let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    sourceAnnotation.title = track.name

    if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
        sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    destinationAnnotation.title = track.name

    if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true)

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

    directions.calculate {
        (response, error) -> Void in

        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
    }


}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) ->     MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0

    return renderer
}



}
```

and this is my NewTracks struct where the data is loaded to/from:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct newTracks {


let name: String!
let trackId: Int!
let postcode: String!
let trackType: String!
let locID: Int!
let lat: Double!
let lon: Double!
let phoneNumber: String!
let email: String!
let rating: Double!
let numrating: Double!
let totalrating: Double!
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?



init(name: String, trackId: Int, postcode: String, trackType: String, trackURL: String, locID: Int, lat: Double, lon: Double, phoneNumber: String, email: String, rating: Double, numrating: Double, totalrating: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.trackId = trackId
    self.ref = nil
    self.postcode = postcode
    self.trackType = trackType
    self.locID = locID
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    self.email = email
    self.rating = rating
    self.numrating = numrating
    self.totalrating = totalrating

}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    trackId = snapshotValue["id"]as! Int
    postcode = snapshotValue["postcode"]as! String
    trackType = snapshotValue["type"]as! String
    locID = snapshotValue["locID"]as! Int
    lat = snapshotValue["lat"]as! Double
    lon = snapshotValue["long"]as! Double
    phoneNumber = snapshotValue["phone"]as! String
    email = snapshotValue["email"]as! String
    rating = snapshotValue["rating"]as! Double
    ref = snapshot.ref
    numrating = snapshotValue["numrating"] as! Double
    totalrating = snapshotValue["totalrating"] as! Double

}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "trackId": trackId,
        "postcode": postcode,
        "trackType": trackType,
        "locID": locID,
        "lat": lat,
        "lon": lon,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        "email": email,
        "rating": rating,
        "numrating": numrating,
        "totalrating": totalrating
            ]
}

}
```

The error happens on the line in the mapLocation VC

```
let sourceloaction = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: track.lat, longitude: track.lon)
```

the lat and lon values are not being passed for some reason.

On my previous VC that the segue worked fine with the data all I had to do was to add the

```
var track: newTracks
```

and this allowed the communication to happen back to where the data is coming from, but for some reason it doesn't appear to be working now.  I know it will be something fundamentally simple I have missed.

This is my original segue code that worked to a normal View COntroller, not a UINavigationController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TrackDetailVC" {
        if let detailsVC = segue.destination as? TrackDetailVC {
            if let tr = sender as? newTracks {
                detailsVC.track = tr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your `func prepare(for segue:)` method on the line `detailsVC.track = tr` If the breakpoint doesn't stop code execution then `sender as? newTracks` must be nil and the problem is earlier in the prep of data for the segue.

Comment: Also, when you mention 'segues into a navigation view with the data' do you mean that the destination VC is embedded in a UINavigationController? If so then your segue code will need to take it into account.

Comment: Add three breakpoints that automatically continue and that simply log a message. They should all go in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`. They should go on three lines in a row starting with `if let detailsVC…`. This will tell you which step is failing and by extension what the issue is. Maybe the segue name is misspelled, maybe the destination is a navigation controller and not your `mapLocation` class, or maybe the sender isn't a `newTracks`. (BTW: Classes should start with capitol letters, instances with lowercase.)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try these.

@Magnas yes its a VC embedded into a UINavigationController.  First time I've used this, is there anything special I need to do?

Comment: Ive added my original segue code that worked to the bottom of the post.  All I have done is changed the identifier of the segue and teh VC it is pointing to

Comment: How is your `struct newTracks {}` becoming the `sender` in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` ? Are you sure the line `detailsVC.track = tr` is being reached?

Comment: What is calling your segue?  Is it a button in the tableViewCell or is the `didSelectRowAt:` delegate calling the segue? In either case, how is that sender conforming to your `newTracks`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when your viewController is embedded in a UINavigationController you have to work through the parts of the chain until you get to the controller you want. Something like this should work:

```
override function prepare(for segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == “TrackDetailVC” {
       if let nav = segue.destinationVC as? UINavigationController {
           if let detailsVC = nav.viewControllers[0] as? TrackDetailVC {
               if let tr = sender as? newTracks {
                   detailsVC.track = tr
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you.  I wasnt aware of the need to go through the UINavigationController and was going straight to my embedded VC.

Comment: nope, thought it had worked but I forgot I had set explicit values for lat and lon.  when I set it back to track.lat and track.lon it fails again with "found nil" error

Comment: It looks like you had two issues. The first was the segue reference to the UINavigationController which my answer addressed showing how to pass data through that kind of segue. The second appears to be related to how you are supplying data. Where are you populating `tr`?

Answer (score 0):

sender can't conform to type newTracks.  Do some debugging with breakpoints and maybe see why this cast isn't working.  Try making a variable called newTracks and explicityly giving it a type, and set it equal to what you want.  Then make `detailsVc.track = newTracks`

Comment: but what I dont get is when I had the same segue pointed at a differentVC it worked perfectly, all I have changed is the Segue ID, and pointed it to a new UINavigationController

Comment: Ive added my original segue code that worked to the bottom of the post.  All I have done is changed the identifier of the segue and teh VC it is pointing to

Comment: the issue lies in that a `UINavigationController` (which is the type of `sender`) cannot conform to type `newTracks`.  I'm not sure why, but that is clearly what is going on.  Attempt the solution I mentioned in my answer, its fairly simple.  Let me know if u have trouble.

Comment: tried this, created a new variable called nTracks as a Double.  Assigned it a value of 1.54333, then made detailsVC = nTracks.  

This fails with "Cannot assign value of type Double to type newTracks

Comment: because detailsVC is of type ViewController and nTracks is of type double...  You have to create a double in that `detailsVC` and do `detailsVC.variable = ntracks`